# how expand a section using two different links?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a webpage with a second navigation menu that, when clicked scrolls down the page to the relevant sections.

In these sections, I have a text area that expands using a click to read more button.

What I am trying to do is implement a feature that will expand this section when the link from the navigation (.toplinks #section1) is clicked too, so that it automatically expands without them having to click the read more button.

```
<li class="top-li-double">
<a class="toplinks" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
</li>
<br/>
<div id="slips" class="explain">
<h2 class="categoryhead">SECTION 1</h2>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
</p>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="small">
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
</p>
</div> 
<div style="margin-top:5px">
<a class="readmoretext" href="#">Click to read more</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The jQuery script:

```
$('.wrapper').find('a[href="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
this.expand = !this.expand;
$(this).text(this.expand?"Read Less":"Click to read more");
$(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.small, .big').toggleClass('small big');
});
```

I have had a play about with this in js fiddle, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxfairydragonxx/fdknjpny/)
 but had no luck. if somebody could give me a push in the right direction, i will be truely thankfull!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rewrote your code a little you can see the full working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fdknjpny/3/).

I've added a few more sections and links so you can see that it scales well.

JS:

```
$('.readmoretext').on('click',function() {
    this.expand = !this.expand;
    $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.small, .big').toggleClass('small big');
    $(this).text(this.expand?"Read Less":"Click to read more");
})


$('a.toplinks').on('click', function (e) {
      var l = $(this).attr('href')
      $(l).find("a.readmoretext").click();
});
```

HTML:

```
<a class="toplinks" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
<div id="section1" class="explain">
```

I've added an `id` to `div.explain` so it scrolls to the element if it can.

Basically the code is just finding the id's a child and calling the `click` event

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic! thank you so much for helping me! :)